# ssh through middle machine with a twist

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy

We have a situation where there are 3 players:

- **L** - computer that the user wants to connect from
- **A** - server that the L can access
- **B** - server that is accessible only through reverse proxy

Idea:

**B** opens a reverse proxy with **A**. Allow **L** computer to access **B** *without* allowing **L** to open a shell on **A**.

I'm not sure if that's possible. Basically **A** should somehow forward any ssh attempt on a specific port to **B** without trying to resolve it itself.

A lot of other solutions rely on having being able to `ssh` into **A** and **B**. That is not ideal since `ssh` access to **A** will expose other computers in that network.

Edit: ideally **B** should only be able to initiate a reverse proxy with **A** and not be able to access anything.

Comment: Why not just use a port-forward?

Comment: It completely slipped my mind. All other research I did point to ssh related solutions in similar scenarios. Something like **L** goes `ssh user@A -p 1234` and the **A** has a redirect using iptables `--dport 1234 --to-port 5678` where the port `5678` is the one used in reverse ssh?

Comment: Exactly. If you can't use iptables you could use stunnel or socat or even nc in user space.